# Kotlin Enum to Default Value in Controller

Tags: kotlin

Problem: I am writing a rest controller which takes in an enum in the RenameRequest parameter shown below.

```
@PutMapping("/rename")
fun rename(@RequestBody @Valid renameRequest: RenameRequest) {
    return imageService.rename(renameRequest.company, 
renameRequest.name, renameRequest.newName)
}
```

The issue is, in my RenameRequest object I initialize the company enum like so:

```
@NotNull
val company: Company? = null
```

This causes problems for me now. These two options of I have thought of, but I do not like either of them

1. Add another enum type that can be "unknown" and it can be initialized to use that, but I do not want to design my code to handle that.
2. I add "!!" saying that I am allowing the enum to be null ex. renameRequest.company!!

I need some input on what a clever solution could be for this.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Kotlin it seems counter-intuitive to me to use a `@NotNull`-annotation but then you say you allow `null`-values for the `company`, i.e. `Company?`.

What about the following?

```
lateinit var company: Company
```